# Is “de” only for cities?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions

I'm a brazilian trying to learn on my own and I want to know about the “de” preposition.

For instance,

> Je suis de New York

is correct, right?

My question is: I can't use “Je suis de Brésil”, can I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that "de" is used for cities, but rather that countries normally (there are some exceptions) take the definite article in French: *Je suis du Brésil*, where *du* is the contracted form of *de le*.

You see the same difference in, e.g. *Je retourne **à** New York* and *Je retourne **au** Brésil*.

Comment: Ok, but using `Je suis`, what's the preposition that should I use? I mean, `Je suis __ Brésil.`.

Comment: It depends on what you want to say - I am in Brazil = Je suis au Brésil / I am from Brazil = Je suis du Brésil.

Comment: I think he's either looking for "Je suis brésilien" (I am brazilian) or "Je viens de Brésil" (I am from Brazil)?

Comment: I would say "Je viens du Brésil" instead of "Je viens de Brésil", for the same reasons Circeus explained.